# How to find the second lowest value in a tensorflow array

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, cluster-analysis

I am writing a clustering algorithm and for part of it I calculate a euclidean distance matrix for each cluster of points. (FYI all of this is in Tensorflow). each cluster is a list of 8 dimensional vectors, which I then turn into one M*8 matrix. For each point in each cluster, I want to find the distance between it and its closest neighbor. I believe the most efficient way to do this would be to do compute pairwise distance between points for each cluster, and then find the second smallest value in each row of the resulting M*M matrix (because the smallest value in each row will always be 0, the distance between a given point and itself).

Here is the code I use to create the euclidean distance matrix for each cluster:

```
    partitionedData = tf.dynamic_partition(inputs, pred, num_classes)
    for partition in partitionedData:
        N = tf.to_int32(partition.get_shape()[0])
        qexpand = tf.expand_dims(partition,1)
        qTexpand = tf.expand_dims(partition,0)
        qtile = tf.tile(qexpand,[1,N,1])
        qTtile = tf.tile(qTexpand,[N,1,1])
        deltaQ = qtile - qTtile
        deltaQ2 = deltaQ*deltaQ
        d2Q = tf.reduce_sum(deltaQ2,2)
```

The resulting matrix might look something like this (Note: this is a matrix of squares of distances):

```
[[  0.   8.   2.  18.]
 [  8.   0.  10.   2.]
 [  2.  10.   0.  20.]
 [ 18.   2.  20.   0.]]
```

for an input matrix of:

```
[[2,3],[4,5],[1,4],[5,6]]
```

What I would like to get in the end is the second smallest value in each row, in this case 2,2,2, and 2. Additionally, if there is a better way to find the distance to the nearest neighbor in tensorflow for every point in a cluster that is computationally efficient, that would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find k-th element in TF you need [tf.nn.top_k](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/top_k). If you need smallest you search not in `X`, but in `-X`.

**In your case you do not even need it.** If your matrix is a distance, the diagonal is always 0 and this screws things up for you. So just create change the diagonal of your matrix with [tf.matrix_set_diag](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/matrix_set_diag), where your diagonal is a vector of size of your X, where each value is [tf.reduce_max](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reduce_max).

Writing a code for this is trivial.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. The tf.matrix_set_diag function is just what I needed. That should make it very simple.